# Getting vertices of segment of polyline using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I have a poly line with 3 co-ordinate, say (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3). Can I get the vertices (x1,y1), (x2,y2) if clicked on line-segment drawn by (x1,y1), (x2,y2)?

I have a poly line on map that with path [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]. And I have electrical box at the corresponding paths.

When clicking the segment drawn by the points x1,y1 and x2,y2 I want to get the point (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Same for path (x2,y2), (x3,y3).

I'm using Javascript API.

Comment: are you experienced with python and arcpy? Then you could program your own toolbar using the ESRI addin_assistent and build an interactive Tool to achieve this.
I don't know about an existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I didn't know you were using Java API when I wrote my answer.

*You are very brief in the explanation of your problem, but I assume you would like to get point features. In order to get the vertices from a polyline you can use the `feature vertices to points` tool from the **data management toolbox**. 
For the newly created point feature class, add an X and a Y field and calculate the geometry.
You may also look at this post: [Get all the points of a polyline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26369/get-all-the-points-of-a-polyline)*