# Extracting vertices from a polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to extract all vertices from 74 polygons in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4, but I don't have any of the advance tools or ArcGIS Pro. I don't have features to points tool as I have checked. What other way can I get the vertices without having to use a different platform. The purple shapefile is the polygon file I am trying to export vertices.

[image]

Comment: The ArcPy documentation shows how to extract vertices by iterating an `arcpy.Geometry` object inside a `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` loop.

Comment: I am not familiar with python. is there a way you could possibly type out for me?

Comment: If you don't have the advance level licenses then you have to use python, it's all in the help file [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/reading-geometries.htm). Don't be shy give it a go!

Comment: [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41053/7424) from over 10 years ago explains how to do this in arcMap. A similar approach would work in ArcGIS Pro.