# Are there are shortcuts for exporting polygon vertex location as a table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, tools, table

Someone came to ask me how he can export the X and Y locations of vertices from his polygon shapefile to excel.

So I told him to convert it to points, add columns, calculate geometry, and then export the attribute table. This isn't too difficult but I found it was quite a long explanation to give for what seems a simple task.

Are there any shortcuts like a tool that will do this in one step? I had a tool through xtools pro and ET Geo-wizards but didn't find anything obvious.

Comment: What you have described does sound to me already like a shortcut :D just in case - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/extract-coordinates-of-polygon-vertices-in-arcmap-10. Or build a script tool.

Comment: Thanks. I think the Add XY coordinates tool brings it down to an acceptable level of steps. And yes if people are doing it all the time I might build a tool.