# Insert vertices coordinates in polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vertices

I have a polygon layer. I extracted the coordinates of vertices, and now I need to add these coordinates in each polygon. The final shapefile should have an attribute table as follows:

[image]

where X1, X2, etc.. are the vertices coordinates for each polygon.

Any ideas on how to do this using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Are you prepared to script it? There is a points to line function which can be polygonized with Feature to Polygon (Advanced license). @Vince is correct 4 points is a triangle as a polygon has the start/end at the same location, if these are boxes/trapezoids you will need to duplicate the first to the last vertex to close it (both arcpy and PyQGIS). I have some arcpy code that could be modified to suit.. but which is it, QGIS or arcgis-desktop? you have both tags; is it that you have both and will accept a solution in either?

Comment: @GrantHumphries I think you should post it on the duplicate question instead, but make sure that you start the answer there by stating something like "This specifically addresses the requirements of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155318/insert-vertices-coordinates-in-polygon", and then ping me again.  My plan is to Merge the two questions so that we can later tidy them up into a more canonical Q&A.