# Labeling polyline vertices with Z value using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3, vertices

I would like to label all polyline vertices of a shape with the z value of each vertex without using export tools like *Entity Vertices to Point* and without creating new field in the attribute table

Comment: Can you please use the Edit button and let us know which software you're using?

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/arcgis-label-last-vertex-z-value/124402#124402 with a bit of efforts it can be achieved. Label can be too long though and slow to redraw

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it's not possible to label the vertices of a polygon (you can only label the polygon itself).

So you'll probably need to:

1. convert the vertices to points
2. calculate the Z value of the points
3. label the points based on the Z value

You could write a Python script which iterates through each polygon, then finds each vertex and obtains the XY coordinates (to create a new point) and its Z value (to give the elevation).

See also [Extracting coordinates of polygon vertices in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/extracting-coordinates-of-polygon-vertices-in-arcmap) which may give some ideas.

Comment: It is doable with advanced labeling http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/arcgis-label-last-vertex-z-value/124402#124402 the question remains why he needs it

Comment: @FelixIP very nice!

Answer (score 3):

This is to add on to [Stephen Lead's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178627/115).

If you don't want to add a column or create an extra point feature class, you could follow Stephen's workflow using temporary files, create annotation instead of labels, then have the script delete the temporary files when it is finished.

I suppose you could create labels and attach them specifically to the existing polygon layer that you are labeling.

FelixIP's process is cool, but it only labels one vertex of the feature. You could create a list, but they wouldn't line up with the vertices.

I don't think there is a way to do this without scripting.